# Is my second for loop able to iterate using the increment from my first loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

What I want is the first loop iterating from `1` to `4` and the second loop from `5` to `6`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 4 ; $i++)
{
    echo $i . "<br>";
}
?>
<hr>
<?php  
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 2 ; $i++)
{
    echo $i . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: No because you re-initialise it in the second for loop to 1

Comment: And checking for `$i<=2` make absolutely NO SENSE if you want to run it to 6

Answer (score 2):

The loops you've given are:
1st loop: from 1 to 4
2nd loop: from 1 to 2

First loop is ok, but seconds needs to be modified. Use `$i<=6` and don't initialize `$i` variable.
This will give you:

1st loop: from 1 to 4
2nd loop: from (value that 1st loop have ended)+1 to 6, so (4+1) to 6, 5 to 6

```
<?php
$i = 0; // be sure 'i' is visible in both loops
for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) // form 1 to 4
{
    echo $i . "<br>";
}
?>
<hr>
<?php  
$i++; // start from 5, not 4
for (; $i<=6; $i++) // from the previous value to 6
{
    echo $i . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Your problem

The second `for` loop resets your `$i` variable to `1`:

```
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 2 ; $i++)
```

### Solution

You can use a [`while` loop](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp) instead of your second `for` loop:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)
{
  echo $i . "<br>";
}
?>

<hr>

<?php
while ($i <= 6) // `<= 6` instead of `<= 2`, since we keep $1's value
{
  echo $i . "<br>";
  $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using two loops for this, why not just output the `<hr>` tag at the appropriate point within the same one? If you carry on with adding extra loops, first of all you'll run into confusing problems like this about (re-)initialising variables, and you'll also quickly end up with a lot of unnecessary duplicated code.

You can use the [PHP modulo operator (%)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to output the `<hr>` tag after every fourth element, which will both reduce the complexity and be a lot more extensible if you later add more elements:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++) {
    echo $i . "<br>";

    if ($i % 4 === 0) {
        echo "<hr>";
    }
}
```

See https://eval.in/976102